# не сохраняются данные в переменную в методе subscribe() RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rxjava

Всем привет. Не могу понять почему в теле метода  subscrube() я присваиваю значение переменной coordinates,и сразу же вывожу значение переменной coordinates в Log и мне отображает нужный мне результат результат, но когда я возвращаю значение переменной coordinates из метода getCoordinates() то возвращает пустую строку. За ранее благодарю за помощь.

```
private val coordinates = ""

private fun getCoordinates(): String? {
        getLastDeviceLocation()
            ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe({
                coordinates = "${it.latitude}, ${it.longitude}"
                Log.i("mLog", coordinates)//  выводит нужные мне координаты
            },
                { Log.i("ERROR", "error = ${it.localizedMessage}") }
            )
        return coordinates // Возвращает пустую строку 
       }
```

Comment: А когда второй раз вызываете какое там значение?

Comment: @AzizUmarov пустая строка. То значение которое изначально было присвоено. Над методом показано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все логично. Вы внутри метода getCoordinates подписываетесь на событие "Получены новые координаты". Еще и слушаете  в главном потоке. У вас нулевая вероятность, что наблюдатель сработает в этот кадр. И у вас сначала отрабатывает метод getCoordines, в котором создается подписка и возвращается пустая еще строка. Через некоторое время наблюдатель получит новые координаты и запишет в вашу переменную, но метод geCoordinates уже давно выполнится.

Вам однозначно не стоит оставлять метод в таком виде. У вас должен быть один метод, который создает подписку и вызывается только один раз, и другой, в котором вы получаете то, что хранится в переменной coordinates, с учетом того что там могло еще ничего не прийти

PS Еще почитайте про disposable. Сейчас вы создаете с каждым вызовом getCoordinates новую подписку, а старые никуда не деваются, у вас утечка памяти

Comment: не могу понять а как тогда такой же самый код из другого класса выполняется корректно, это код из того же проекта но из другого класса http://prntscr.com/t603bn

Comment: @Artem ну, код по ссылке работает не так. Он при вызове кладет в переменную специальное значение, говорящее что данные сейчас загружаются, и создает подписку, которая запишет туда необходимые данные как только они придут. В итоге данные есть всегда, какое-то время они, так сказать, пустые, в какой-то момент заполняются. В вашем коде это тоже присутствует, но вы пытаетесь сразу из метода вернуть результат, не дожидаясь выполнения запроса

Comment: @Artem ну и утечка памяти в том коде по сссылке тоже есть. Чтобы ее не было надо  перед disposable = блаблабла поставить disposable?.dispose(). Старую подписку убиваем, затем создаем новую

Comment: чего-то я наверно не догоняю, потому-что разницы между кодом который я опубликовал в вопросе и кодом по ссылке не вижу. Инициализация переменной coordinates происходит в методе subscribe который в свою очередь выполняется в главном потоке, и как я понимаю пока эта инициализация не пройдет из метода getCoordinates ничего возвращаться не будет

Comment: @Artemсам по себе метод getCoordinates синхронный, то есть все команды выполнятся в том порядке, в котором перечислены, строго друг за другом. У вас следующие команды выполняются: получаем объект Observable, подписываемся на него, возвращаем текущее значение coordinates как результат функции. Тот код, что передается внутрь метода subscribe выполнен внутри getCoordinates не будет, это набор команд который мы передали в Observable, чтобы тот их выполнил когда придет время. Потому к тому моменту как выполнится retern переменная coordinates все еще будет пустой

Comment: Кажется я понял вас. Получается метод subscribe выполняется не в методе getCoordinates, то-есть эти два метода выполняются в одном главном потоке но метод subscribe выполняется с запозданием

Comment: @Artem Не совсем. Сам метод subscribe выполняется тут же, но в параметрах вы указываете два блока кода, которые ограничены {}. первый выполнится, когда данные о местоположении будут получены, второй - если во время получения произойдет ошибка. Это примерно как OnClickListener. Можно написать в методе onCreate примерно так view.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(...).show() }. Сам setOnClickListener отработает при запуске активити, а вот код в {}, который передан в параметры, выполнится позже, когда кто-то тапнет по кнопке. Так и тут. subscribe - это setOnClick, приход координат - тап

Comment: Получается с запозданием выполняется не метод subscribe а два блока кода которые находятся в этом методе, в моем случае это метод onSuccess  и onError. А как решить эту проблему? Я так понял что возвращать из метода getCoordinates ничего не нужно, а нужно просто менять значение переменной coordinates в методе subscribe. Значение переменной coordinates я использую в апи запросе, как сделать так чтоб дождаться пока в переменную coordinates попадет нужное мне значение и только потом делать апи запрос? с помощью LiveData?

Comment: @Artem увы, я не знаю как это объяснить... это не баг, это фича. Rx создан для того, что это работало с запозданием, потому что ждать отработки некоторых вещей абсурдно долго. Поэтому вместо того, чтоб ждать пока операционная система соизволит связаться со спутниками, просчитать координаты и отдать тебе проще сказать что делать, когда это произойдет и идти заниматься другими делами. Вам нужно организовать свой код так, чтобы он работал по такой концепции и мирился с тем, что первые секунды у вас данных не будет. По хорошему вам надо подписывать на обновления ту вьюшку,Которая использует данные

Comment: ok.  главное что я понял причину, это самое главное, а дальше уже не сложно будет. Спасибо большое за помощь